# Cannot get a Substring of a substring

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to parse a String from a file that looks something like this:

```
Mark Henry, Tiger Woods, James the Golfer, Bob,
3, 4, 5, 1,
1, 2, 3, 5,
6, 2, 1, 4,
```

For ease of use, I'd like to split off the first line of the String, because it will be the only one that cannot be converted into integer values (the rest will be stored in a double array of integers[line][value]);

I tried to use `String.split("\\\n")` to divide out each line into its own String, which works.  However, I am unable to divide the new strings into substrings with `String.split("\\,")`.  I am not sure what is going on:

```
    String[] firstsplit = fileOne.split("\\\n");
    System.out.println("file split into " + firstsplit.length + " parts");

    for (int i = 0; i < firstsplit.length; i++){
        System.out.println(firstsplit[i]);  // prints values to verify it works
    }

    String firstLine = firstsplit[0];
    String[] secondSplit = firstLine.split("\\,");
    System.out.println(secondSplit[0]);  // prints nothing for some reason
```

I've tried a variety of different things with this, and nothing seems to work (copying over to a new String is an attempt to get it to work even).  Any suggestions?

EDIT: I have changed it to `String.split(",")` and also tried `String.split(", ")`  but I still get nothing to print afterwards.

It occurs to me now that maybe the first location is a blank one....after testing I found this to be true and everything works for `firstsplit[1]`;

Comment: You do not need to escape a comma.

Comment: it's just "," no need to escape it with "\," or "\\,"

Comment: `s.split(", ")` will do that: `,` doesn't have a special meaning in a regex context.

Comment: I hate when it is that simple.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to split `\\,`, which translates to the actual value `\,`. You want to escape only `,`.

Comment: Yeah, escaping regular expressions and the like it super confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Comma `,` doesn't need `\` before it as it isn't a special character. Try using `,` instead of `\\,`, which is translated to `\,` (not only a comma, also a backslash).

Answer (score 0):

Not only do you not need to escape a comma, but you also don't need three backslashes for the newline character:

```
String[] firstSplit = fileOne.split("\n");
```

That will work just fine. I tested your code with the string you specified, and it actually worked just fine, and it also worked just fine splitting without the extraneous escapes...

Have you actually tested it with the String data you provided in the question, or perhaps is the actual data something else. I was worried about the carriage return (`\r\n` in e.g. Windows files), but that didn't matter in my test, either. If you can scrub the String data you're actually parsing, and provide a sample output of the original String (`fileOne`), that would help significantly.

Answer (score 0):

You could just load the file into a list of lines:

```
fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));
String line = null;
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
while (( line = bin.readLine()) != null ) {
    lines.add( line );
}
fin.close();
```

Of course you have to include this stuff into some try catch block which fits into your exception handling. Then parse the lines starting with the second one like this:

```
for ( int i = 1; i < lines.size(); i++ ) {
    String[] values = lines.get( i ).split( "," );
}
```